# Why is operator from base class called in templates?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overriding, operator-keyword

Why is `B::operator()` called for both `B` and `D` in the program below?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class B {
public:
  virtual ~B() {}
  virtual bool operator()(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
};

class D : public B {
public:
  bool operator()(int a, int b) override { return a > b; }
};

void f(B& b, std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), b);
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  const std::vector<int> v{5, 3, 8, 1, 7};

  std::vector<int> vb(v);
  B b;
  f(b, vb);

  std::vector<int> vd(v);
  D d;
  f(d, vd);

  return 0;
}
```

If I change `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), b)` to this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
          [&](int x, int y){ return b.operator()(x, y); });
```

then `f(d, vd)` sorts backwards as expected.

My best understanding is that `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), b)` uses `&B::operator()` rather than `b.operator()`. I couldn't find a clear explanation though, and it doesn't seem entirely logical since the compiler should be able to see that `B` has a vtable.

Comment: `std::sort` takes the comparator by value. The real lesson here is that non-leaf base classes should be abstract, which would avoid precisely this kind of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the signature of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

The parameter `comp` will be passed by value here, so for `f(d, vd);`, `d` will be [slicing copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to `B` and then `B::operator()` will be invoked.

You might make `f()` a template function.

```
template <typename COMP>
void f(COMP& b, std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), b);
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Other suggestion: It'll be better to make `B::operator()` and `D::operator()` const member function, and change the parameter type of `b` to const reference.

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/QWXEW56689)</kbd>

Comment: Along with the (somewhat off-topic but valuable) const correctness advice for the `operator()` member functions; possibly worth adding to also let argument `b` in `f` be a const reference.

Comment: @dfri Sure, added. In fact I've done it in my live demo. :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't check tha live demo :)